# easy-thumbnails: Using the scale_and_crop image processor in a thumbnail alias

Tags: django, thumbnails, easy-thumbnails

I can't figure out the proper format to use in specifying that specs for the [scale_and_crop](http://easy-thumbnails.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/processors/#easy_thumbnails.processors.scale_and_crop) image processor in a [thumbnail alias](http://easy-thumbnails.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/#thumbnail-aliases).

I've tried many variations, most recently this one:

```
'year_thumb': {
    'scale_and_crop': (
        ('size', (120, 0)),
        ('crop', 'scale'),
        ('upscale', True),
    )
},
```

Not sure how to get this right.

Answer (score 3):

So, unfortunately I never reconciled the setting of image processor arguments in code vs. in thumbnail alias settings, but here's how I accomplished the same, or similar thing:

```
'year_thumb': {
    'size': (120, 0),
    'autocrop': True,
    'crop': 'smart',
    'upscale': True,
},
```